# Internet Explorer opens links to .msi files as text in a new tab

Tags: functions, htaccess

I'm really struggling with this issue.

The WordPress site I manage has had .msi files available to download for a long time. Since the recent update to WordPress 3.8, Internet Explorer no longer downloads .msi files correctly. Instead, it opens a new tab and displays thousands of lines of garbage code. Even if you right click and save as, the extension shows up as .htm instead of .msi.

Chrome and Firefox continue to download the .msi files correctly. Only IE has this issue.

CPanel shows the .msi files having the MIME-type application/octet-stream, so what I believe is the correct MIME-type is being sent to IE.

In the functions.php file, I found the following:

`function send_nosniff_header() {

        @header( 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff' );

}`

Which, ideally, would tell IE to not sniff the MIME-type... But I have no idea if it is correct. Or in the correct spot.

I didn't create this site, I'm only trying to maintain. And to make things more interesting, I'm brand new to WordPress. So if anyone has any ideas that might help, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: Not really a WP question and it may be closed due to the WPSE FAQ

Comment: I hope this question isn't closed... I haven't been able to get a reply out of anyone, anywhere else. I believe this to be directly related to WP based on the fact that .msi files were downloaded properly by all browsers, including IE, until I updated to WP 3.8. Something in that update changed how IE handles these files.

Answer (score 1):

That function does prevent IE from detecting mime types, which is why IE opens the file in a new tab rather than downloading it.

Delete the function and see if .msi files are then downloaded.

See [MIME-Handling Changes in Internet Explorer - IEBlog - MSDN Blogs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/mime-handling-changes-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Thank you for responding. As I mentioned above, I haven't had any luck anywhere else.

I removed that function and it did stop opening a new tab, however it still just displays garbage text/code instead of downloading the file. When I right-click/save-as it still changes the extension to .htm.